# Black Arrow Status Item

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I am working on a IM client for OS X, and I have the design in mind, but I need help with the code.
On Snow Leopard, when you click a dock item, you get something like this:

[Image 1 http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/8199/screenshot20091121at223.png](http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/8199/screenshot20091121at223.png)

What I was thinking of was something like that: (photoshop)

[Image 2 http://img442.imageshack.us/img442/4860/sanstitre1kfy.jpg](http://img442.imageshack.us/img442/4860/sanstitre1kfy.jpg)

This is the basic idea, but it has to be resizable so that it can include more stuff, like so (still photoshop).

[Image 3 http://img121.imageshack.us/img121/3578/longversion.jpg](http://img121.imageshack.us/img121/3578/longversion.jpg)

I would need a basic implementation of it, and I can easily sub-view it to do the insides, but it has to be resizable easily.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "resizable easily"?

Comment: What I meant was that I can easily add more text without any problem... that was maybe a dumb thing to say. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [MAAttachedWindow](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/03/04/using-maattachedwindow-with-an-nsstatusitem) ...

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to give Matt Gemmell (the author) credit if per his license you use his work in your app. Easily overlooked, but fair's fair. :-)