# Snow Leopard Style Pop-Ups

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Is there a framework that draws Snow Leopard style popups? For an example of what I am talking about, try right clicking something in the dock. I basically want to be able to give a starting point (where the arrow forms) and then a size and have it do the rest.

In this case it's a menu, though my use would be more of just for drawing a popup.

Comment: Similar / same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779028/black-arrow-status-item

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out Matt Gemmell's [MAAttachedWindow](http://mattgemmell.com/2007/10/03/maattachedwindow-nswindow-subclass). It does exactly what you need: lets you specify a starting point, orientation, and the view which should be placed inside the popup.